# Vuetify 3 Data Table display nested object

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am struggling with the approach to display a nested object in a vuetify data table.
I am able to render data as long as it sits on top level of the API payload. Now I would need to display a nested element of the object.

The docs state that the component is able to use dot notation but cant get my head around :S
[Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/#headers)

THX for help

I tried the following code:

Data Table:

```
<v-data-table 
          :headers="headers"
          :items="business_group"
          :search="search"
          
          @click:row="onRowClick(item.id)"
          class="elevation-1 "
          style="height: 715px;"
          > 
          <template v-slot:item="{ item }" >
            <tr >
              <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.location }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.lead_auditor.first_name }}</td>
              <td>
                <v-btn class="mx-2" size="small" color="primary" @click="onRowClickEdit(item.id)"><v-icon icon="mdi-playlist-edit" ></v-icon></v-btn>
                <v-btn size="small" color="deep-purple-lighten-2" @click="onRowClickDelete(item.id)"><v-icon icon="mdi-trash-can-outline" ></v-icon></v-btn>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
```

Headers:

```
headers: [
           {
             title: 'Name',
             align: 'start',
             key: 'name',
           },
           { title: 'Ort', key: 'location' },
           { title: 'Lead Auditor', value: 'lead_auditor.first_name' },
           { title: 'Aktionen', key: 'actions'},
          ],
```

Backend payload:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "A company Name",
    "location": "Mordor",
    "lead_auditor": {
      "id": 1,
      "is_active": true,
      "username": "mm",
      "first_name": "Timmy",
      "last_name": "foo",
      "initials": "MM",
      "email": "my.email@mail.com"
    }
  },
```

When running the code the data table says: "No data available".

**EDIT (full code base):**

```
<template>
    <v-data-table 
      :headers="headers"
      :items="business_group"
      :search="search"

      @click:row="onRowClick(item.id)"
      class="elevation-1 "
      style="height: 715px;"
      > 
      <template v-slot:item="{ item }" >
        <tr >
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.location }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.lead_auditor.firt_name }}</td>
          <td>
            <v-btn class="mx-2" size="small" color="primary" @click="onRowClickEdit(item.id)"><v-icon icon="mdi-playlist-edit" ></v-icon></v-btn>
            <v-btn size="small" color="deep-purple-lighten-2" @click="onRowClickDelete(item.id)"><v-icon icon="mdi-trash-can-outline" ></v-icon></v-btn>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
</template>
  
<script >
import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'  
     export default {
      components: {
      VDataTable
   },
       data () {
         return {
          business_group: [{
            id: 2,
            name: "A company Name",
            location: "Mordor",
            lead_auditor: {
                id: 1,
                is_active: true,
                username: "mm",
                first_name: "Timmy",
                last_name: "foo",
                initials: "MM",
                email: "my.email@mail.com"
            }
        }
        ],
          headers: [
           {
             title: 'Name',
             align: 'start',
             key: 'name',
           },
           { title: 'Ort', key: 'location' },
           { title: 'Lead Auditor', value: 'lead_auditor.first_name' },
           { title: 'Aktionen', key: 'actions'},
          ],
        }
       },
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Dot notation should work. Problem is probably elsewhere like reactivity or something.. Can you recreate your example in a stackblitz or something?

Comment: Sorry sir, I tried to use stackblitz but cant include vuetify correctly, I tried it with installing the dependencies. But then the app chrashes. I will try to fix it, in the mean time I copied the full page code in the body (reduced to the problem). The code base represents my issue as well.
Because you mentioned reactivity, I recognized that I did not imported the { ref } dep .

Comment: I guess reactivity was the right direction. Thanks to @fOURP! 
I wrote the data section wrong.
Solution was to use the data: () => ({ }) notation and NOT data () { }

Comment: Glad you figured it out! :)